# what are the remmina default ssh options?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, remote-desktop, rdp, vnc

What are the remmina's default ssh options?
I have changed them and now I dont know what to do, I cant uninstall and reinstall it cause I will lose my credentials. There is no reset button either.

What are the default ssh options?
I have changed them this way and as a result now my ssh connections disconnect very quickly after inactivity. Any help? Anyone haven't changed their settings please post the default settings so that I can revert it. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default options for remmina

[image]